# How move certain files based on their numbers?

Tags: r

I have a text file contain (head):

```
"Grid.Point.Index" "Latitude" "Longitude" "Cell"
"544361" 2093507 40.071983 0 1322
"545570" 2098421 40.184559 0 1322
"545571" 2098423 40.184559 0.146776 1322
"546781" 2103327 40.297134 0 1322
"546782" 2103329 40.297134 0.14702 1322
"546784" 2103333 40.297134 0.294039 1322
```

to read the file:

```
table= read.table("C:\\Users\\lonlatnter.txt", sep=",",header=TRUE)
```

with each number in the second column there is an associated file in another folder`data`.
I have thousands of files in this folder so called `"data"`.

to list the files:

```
data<- list.files("D:\\data", "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```

the files are named as(example) `data_num_gp2103333.csv`

the number in the name after `gp` corresponds to the second column in the text file.

I want to move (or copy) only files with numbers exist in the second column in the text file from the  folder `data` to a new folder `mydata`.
Any helps please.

```
str( table )

'data.frame':   374 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Grid.Point.Index: int  2093507 2098421 2098423 2103327 2103329 2103333 2108225 2108227 
                         2108231 2113115 ...
$ Latitude        : num  40.1 40.2 40.2 40.3 40.3 ...
$ Longitude       : num  0 0 0.147 0 0.147 ...
$ Cell            : int  1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 1322 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the example below. First we loop over each `Index` value in your `table` (side-note - there is a function called `table()` so I'd avoid calling a variable this). We list the files that contain this index value. I am assuming each index value relates to a single file. That being the case, we return a character vector of file names.

Next we loop over the file names, copying each file to the folder `"D:/NewData"` (which must already exist on your drive). the file will have the original filename, just in a new folder. I use a `for` loop for this, because a) execution time of the loop is negligible compared to the time it takes to do the `file.copy` and b) because we call `file.copy` for it's side-effect (copying a file from/to the specified locations) rather than it's return value (a logical indicating whether or not the copy was succesful).

```
fls <- sapply( table[,2] , function(x) list.files( path = "D:\\data"  , pattern = as.character( x ) , full.names = TRUE ) )

#  Use a 'for' loop here because we are calling the
#  file.copy function for it's side effect rather
#  than return value (i.e. to copy a file)
for( i in fls ){
    file.copy( from = i , to = paste0( "D:/NewData/" , basename( i ) ) )
}
```

Comment: @sacvf that's your problem. Please describe your data properly.

Comment: If that is true the `table[,2]` should refer to the second column.

Comment: @sacvf so the seperator in your `data` file is not `","`, it's possibly `" "` , i.e. whitespace.

Comment: Post the `str( table )`

Comment: @sacvf ok, it's hard to test because there is no reproducible data (it is hard for this problem), however I think the problem stems from the fact that `Grid.Point.Index` is an integer, not a character. Simple fix. Check the edited version above. *Please* tell me we have it working now.